# using a classes functions in the global space in php?

Tags: php

Is it possible to extract all methods out of a class instance and use them in the global space?

Say I have:

```
class Library {
  public function num_one() { echo "number one"; }
  public function num_two() { echo "number two"; }
}
```

After I load the class, I want to be able to use the functions without specifying the instance

```
include '/path/to/library-class.php';
$lib = new Library();

#$lib->num_one();
#$lib->num_two();

num_one();
num_two();
```

Comment: You're doing it wrong... If you really need to use functions and classes like that, which you probably don't, you could create wrapper functions in the function's include file.

Comment: @G-Nugget thanks for the idea of wrapping, but it doesn't look like a convenient solution; for one i'd have to write out every function i want to wrap and for another i'd have to pass the instance variable in each case?

Comment: In this case I would tell you that you don't need to use `class` instead you can use `procedural` approach, keep all functions in a file and include them before you use them.

Comment: @SheikhHeera I guess thats it then

Answer (score 1):

You could make them static, for example

```
class Library {
    public static function num_one() { echo "number one"; }
    public static function num_two() { echo "number two"; }
}
```

then you could use

```
Library::num_one()
Library::num_two()
```

You also wouldn't need the '$lib = new Library();' line then :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you'd need to do this, because one of the advantages of OOP is to encapsulate methods into namespaces safely and prevent collisions of function names.

However, if you absolutely need to do this (and I think you can and should refactor in a way to not have to do this), it can be done; you can add this to /path/to/library-class.php:

```
class Library {
    public function num_one() { echo "number one"; }
    public function num_two() { echo "number two"; }
}

$global_Library = new Library();

function num_one ($whateverParameter) {
    global $global_Library;
    return $global_Library->num_one($whateverParameter);
}
// Continue adding your wrapper functions here.
```

I'd still think that using static methods are better than what you're asking to do, even though they shouldn't be treated as a cure-all.

http://code.google.com/p/google-singleton-detector/wiki/WhySingletonsAreControversial

Comment: This is what @G-Nugget suggested, however this is what I'm trying to avoid! I was hoping there would be a method similar to the `extract` function for variables.

Comment: @Stegrex Completely right its an anti-pattern to use static in such a way really...

Comment: @JamesLeckenby I still think your solution using the static is better than what I'm offering, but the correct solution is simply to instantiate an object and use the object's methods at the point where you need them, although OP doesn't want to use that. Well, I guess if a person really doesn't want to use OOP for its advantages, that's just a personal choice (shrugs).

Comment: @Stegrex I'm trying to build a wordpress-style theme loader, for that I wanted to find a way of doing this, because the template files would be much easier if they just have function names e.g. get_header() not Something::get_header()